# FFTrees in R gives Error in cats[match(names(xlevels), colnames(X))] <- unlist(lapply(xlevels, : NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments

Tags: r

I'm using FFTrees package in R.

When I run the following code for building `FFTrees`:

```
fft <- FFTrees(formula = todimkrankenhaus ~ .-ccs.diab.nc-gefaesse, data = up_train, data.test = test)
```

I run into the following error message:

> Error in cats[match(names(xlevels), colnames(X))] <- unlist(lapply(xlevels,  : 
>     NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments

I was wondering what might be the cause of the error and how to fix it?

Comment: Please check if the column names match

Comment: Thank you! After excluding the variables "ccs.diab.nc" and "gefaesse" from the test set, now the function works fine.